# How to simulate a touch outside of AlertDialog window on android with espresso

Tags: android, testing, integration-testing, android-espresso

My Dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3' 
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3' 
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2' 
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') { 
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7' 
} 
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

I can´t find a way to simulate a click outside of an AlertDialog window to check something when it closes...

How can I do it?

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Rakesh is not solved :(

Answer (score 5):

Check [my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018633/4631359)

Espresso can't do this.

You need to use **uiautomator** inside your Espresso test, add this to your project's gradle:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
```

After your dialog appears, you can click on the screen at any coordinate:

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
        device.click(x,y);
```

That will close your dialog

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in many cases by creating a custom ClickAction:

```
    public static ViewAction clickXY(final int x, final int y){
    return new GeneralClickAction(
            Tap.SINGLE,
            new CoordinatesProvider() {
                @Override
                public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {

                    final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);

                    final float screenX = screenPos[0] + x;
                    final float screenY = screenPos[1] + y;
                    float[] coordinates = {screenX, screenY};

                    return coordinates;
                }
            },
            Press.FINGER);
}
```

Then you can locate a known view in your dialog (say the 'OK' button) and invoke it as follows:

```
onView(withText("OK")).perform(clickXY(-200, 200));
```

Obviously, the x/y values that you use will be dependent upon your particular situation.

Comment: This yields `InjectEventSecurityException: Check if Espresso is clicking outside the app (system dialog, navigation bar if edge-to-edge is enabled, etc.).` in Espresso 3.5.1