# Android testing: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-uiautomator, android-espresso

In Android Ui testing, I want to click on a spinner item in a dialog, but it pop up with this error:

```
va.lang.RuntimeException: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not be requesting layout for over 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Otherwise, something is seriously wrong. Selected Root:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2dac97c7, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2dac97c7, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#10 ty=1 fl=#81810100 pfl=0x8 wanim=0x1030461 surfaceInsets=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) mwfl=0x0}, decor-view-string=MultiPhoneDecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1600, height=2560, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}
. All Roots:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3c913e1, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@21b23506, has-window-focus=true, layout-params-type=1002, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(310,600)(722x480) gr=#10000033 sim=#1 ty=1002 fl=#1860200 fmt=-3 wanim=0x10302db surfaceInsets=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) mwfl=0x0}, decor-view-string=PopupViewContainer{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=722, height=480, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3c913e1, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3c913e1, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=2, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(wrapxwrap) gr=#11 sim=#20 ty=2 fl=#1800002 pfl=0x8 fmt=-3 wanim=0x1030462 surfaceInsets=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) mwfl=0x10}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1136, height=1058, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2dac97c7, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2dac97c7, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#10 ty=1 fl=#81810100 pfl=0x8 wanim=0x1030461 surfaceInsets=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) mwfl=0x0}, decor-view-string=MultiPhoneDecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1600, height=2560, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}
at android.support.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:99)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule.java:69)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:23)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:9)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:68)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:120)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I have tried

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)),containsString("A4"))).inRoot(isPlatformPopup()).perform(click());
```

and

```
onView(withText(containsString("A4"))).inRoot(isFocusable()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

and

```
onView(withText(containsString("A4"))).inRoot(withDecorView(not(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

but none of them works...
Can anyone tell me how to get the ralavant root please?

Answer (score 29):

This error can happen when a system dialog is displayed — like `"Power Off"` or `"Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped"` (a background app has crashed) — and you try to run an Espresso unit test whilst that dialog is visible.

[image: Android system dialog: Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped.]

<sub>*Image credit: [Android 4.0 emulator always has a crashing Launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155417/android-4-0-emulator-always-has-a-crashing-launcher)*</sub>

You can workaround it in code by dismissing the system dialog before running the test:

#### app/build.gradle

```bash
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0"
}
```

#### MyActivityTest.java

```java
@BeforeClass
public static void dismissAppCrashSystemDialogIfShown() {
    try {
        UiDevice
            .getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
            .executeShellCommand(
                "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }

    // The previous way of doing this was to use Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS.
    // But as of September 2023, when compiling against API 31 (Android 12), this will
    // give a deprecation warning. The technique is shown below for historical reasons.

    // Use the 'testing' Context
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));

    // Alternative: Use the Activity for the Context
    MyActivity activityUnderTest = activityTestRule.getActivity();
    activityUnderTest.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
}
```

Or send the broadcast on the command line using adb:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
```

---

Another cause of the error is when a background app is frozen ([ANR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213482/what-is-the-difference-between-anr-and-crash-in-android)) or is running slowly, and a system dialog appears saying `"Launcher isn't responding. Do you want to close it? [Wait] [OK]"`:

[image: Android system dialog: Launcher isn't Responding. Do you want to close it? Wait, OK]

<sub>*Image credit: https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/08/introducing-and-open-sourcing-test-butler--reliable-android-test*</sub>

If you try to run an Espresso test while this dialog is visible, the tests will all fail and show the "Waited for the root..." error. There's no easy way to close this dialog programmatically. Espresso cannot click these buttons, for the reasons described here:  [Dismiss Alert Dialog in Android Espresso Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288798/dismiss-alert-dialog-in-android-espresso-test) . However, one way is to use **UI Automator** to press the "Wait" button in the dialog, just before a test starts:

#### app/build.gradle

```bash
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0"
}
```

#### ActivityUiTest.kt

```java
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @BeforeClass
    fun dismissANRSystemDialog() {
        val device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())
        // If running the device in English Locale
        var waitButton = device.findObject(UiSelector().textContains("wait"))
        if (waitButton.exists()) {
            waitButton.click()
        }
        // If running the device in Japanese Locale
        waitButton = device.findObject(UiSelector().textContains("待機"))
        if (waitButton.exists()) {
            waitButton.click()
        }
    }
}
```

#### ActivityUiTest.java

```java
@BeforeClass
public static void dismissANRSystemDialog() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
    // If the device is running in English Locale
    UiObject waitButton = device.findObject(new UiSelector().textContains("wait"));
    if (waitButton.exists()) {
        waitButton.click();
    }
    // If the device is running in Japanese Locale
    waitButton = device.findObject(new UiSelector().textContains("待機"));
    if (waitButton.exists()) {
        waitButton.click();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use adb on the command line to send [screen taps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437686/how-to-use-adb-to-send-touch-events-to-device-using-sendevent-command) or [key strokes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/KeyEvent.java) to dismiss it. For example:

```bash
# On a 320x480 screen, click at screen location [x=233,y=293] to tap an "OK" dialog button.
# Just in case there is a "Launcher isn't responding" system dialog.
adb shell input tap 233 293
```

or

```bash
# Send keystroke Arrow Right
sleep 3; adb shell input keyevent 22
# Send keystroke Arrow Right again
sleep 3; adb shell input keyevent 22
# Send keystroke Enter to press a button on the dialog
sleep 3; adb shell input keyevent 66
```

**More info:**

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-test-kit-discuss/yIEwus_hjeY
- [How to dismiss system dialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013790/how-to-dismiss-system-dialog-in-android)
- [Android adb shell am broadcast: Bad component name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171354/android-adb-shell-am-broadcast-bad-component-name)
- [How to use ADB to send touch events to device using sendevent command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437686/how-to-use-adb-to-send-touch-events-to-device-using-sendevent-command)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was facing

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error, when I used a Spinner inside a DialogFragment.
This is the only code that was working for me:

```
onView(withText(containsString("A4"))).inRoot(isPlatformPopup()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: This solved my problem when using a Spinner inside an `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue when a dialog popup contains spinner items (dropdown list), my click couldn't perform on any of the spinner items and got the same error.
I found a solution by using onData() method with RootMatchers:

```
onData(anything()).inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup()).atPosition(1).perform(click());
```

Note that, the index value in ***atPosition()*** is the item's index value from the spinner list.

Answer (score 3):

For me, when testing my custom `AlertDialog`, using the `.inRoot(isDialog())` method instead of `.inRoot(isPlatformPopup())` worked.

```
onView(withText(containsString("A4"))).inRoot(isDialog()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue periodically when running Espresso tests on emulators in CI.  Because the checks fail if a single test fails, the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54203607/4520965 was insufficient for my use case.  That answer handles dismissing the ANR Dialogue in the subsequent test class, but the test class where the ANR initially appeared would still fail.  To get around this I added the following to my base ui test class that all my Espresso tests inherited from:

```
    //Running count of the number of Android Not Responding dialogues to prevent endless dismissal.
    private var AnrCount = 0 
    //`RootViewWithoutFocusException` class is private, need to match the message (instead of using type matching).
    private val rootViewWithoutFocusExceptionMsg = java.lang.String.format(
            Locale.ROOT,
            "Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have "
                    + "window focus and not request layout for 10 seconds. If you specified a non "
                    + "default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. "
                    + "Root:")

    @Before
    fun setUpHandler() {
        Espresso.setFailureHandler { error, viewMatcher ->
            
            if (error.message!!.contains(rootViewWithoutFocusExceptionMsg) && AnrCount < 3) {
                AnrCount++
                handleAnrDialogue()
            } else { // chain all failures down to the default espresso handler
                DefaultFailureHandler(context).handle(error, viewMatcher)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleAnrDialogue() {
        val device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())
        // If running the device in English Locale
        val waitButton = device.findObject(UiSelector().textContains("wait"))
        if (waitButton.exists()) waitButton.click()
    }
```

Comment: I could compare the error type using reflection: `Class<?> c = Class.forName("androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker$RootViewWithoutFocusException")`

Comment: I found that my tests still fails even though the dialog closes. It seems like the failure handler gets triggered by an input event, but that event does not automatically get replayed after the dialog has closed.

Comment: Calling `DefaultFailureHandler()` when there is another Espresso failure avoids me to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54231813/3014115) solution when I need to wait for a view using an IdlingResource.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if it happens to anyone's Travis build (with exact the same log).  Please check [this](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6340#issuecomment-262166193).

Had exact the same problem, and solved by **creating avd with lower target version (19)**.

What I've tried and didn't work:

- Adding a `unlockScreen()` `@Before` method to UI test.
- Adding / Removing `adb shell input keyevent 82 &`.
- Removing different `emulator` command options `-no-skin` or `-no-audio` or `-no-window`.  Now I have `-no-window` there which is fine.

Finally, changing
from

```
echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-24 --abi armeabi-v7a
```

to

```
echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-19 --abi armeabi-v7a
```

perfectly solve the issue.

Comment: So basically you are recommending to run all tests on Android 4.4 (a downgrade from Android 7.0 you were previously using). I don't think this is a viable solution...

Answer (score 0):

just update the build tools in the travis.yml:

- In this file `.travis.yml`: you should have this `before_install: - echo yes | android update sdk --all --filter build-tools-26.0.1 --no-ui --force`
- as wel this in `.travis.yml`:

```yml
script: echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-22
--abi armeabi-v7a emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window & 
android-wait-for-emulator 
adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
adb shell input keyevent 82 &
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is newly up to date, but with the new Android version.
AndroidX Test: 1.3.0
Espresso: 3.3.0
Android OS: Android 11 (API 30)
See https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/751

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but in my case, I had a debug tooltip overlapping the button I needed to click.

To solve this problem, I only changed the production code to avoid showing this tooltip to my UI tests

I have a utility class that knows when the UI tests are running:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.app.UITestEnvironment");
    inUITestEnvironment = true;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
    // We're not in a UI test environment
    inUITestEnvironment = false;
}
```