# Is it possible to use Espresso's IdlingResource to wait until a certain view appears?

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-espresso

In my test I have a stage where after pressing a button application does a lot of asynchronous calculations and requests to the cloud service, after which it displays a certain view.

Is it possible to use Espresso's `IdlingResource` implementation to wait until a certain view appears?

I've read an answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417954/espresso-thread-sleep) and comments seems to suggest that you can use `IdlingResource` instead, but I don't understand how. Espresso does not seem to have any built-in way to handle long operations, but having to write your own waiting loops feels like a hack.

Any way to solve this or should I just do as the answer in the linked thread suggests?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your IdlingResource could look like this:

```
import android.support.test.espresso.IdlingResource;
import android.support.test.espresso.ViewFinder;
import android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction;
import android.view.View;

import org.hamcrest.Matcher;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;

public class ViewShownIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    private static final String TAG = ViewShownIdlingResource.class.getSimpleName();

    private final Matcher<View> viewMatcher;
    private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

    public ViewShownIdlingResource(final Matcher<View> viewMatcher) {
        this.viewMatcher = viewMatcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        View view = getView(viewMatcher);
        boolean idle = view == null || view.isShown();

        if (idle && resourceCallback != null) {
            resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
        }

        return idle;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this + viewMatcher.toString();
    }

    private static View getView(Matcher<View> viewMatcher) {
        try {
            ViewInteraction viewInteraction = onView(viewMatcher);
            Field finderField = viewInteraction.getClass().getDeclaredField("viewFinder");
            finderField.setAccessible(true);
            ViewFinder finder = (ViewFinder) finderField.get(viewInteraction);
            return finder.getView();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you could create a helper method waiting for your view:

```
public void waitViewShown(Matcher<View> matcher) {
    IdlingResource idlingResource = new ViewShownIdlingResource(matcher);///
    try {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(idlingResource);
        onView(matcher).check(matches(isDisplayed()));  
    } finally {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(idlingResource);
    }    
}
```

Finally, in your test:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
    waitViewShown(withId(R.id.<some>));

    //do whatever verification needed afterwards    
}
```

You could improve this example by making IdlingResource wait for any condition, not just for the visibility one.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct solution: 1. Google tells you not to use `onTransitionToIdle` from `isIdleNow()` in their docs,  2. If I understand correctly this will just check the resource once when `onView` is called and if the resource is not idle by that time, it will hang.

Comment: 1) Could you share a link for this? 2) It will be checking it multiple times until after the condition is met or the check for the idling resource times out.

Comment: Nevertheless, I agree with you that wait for a view should have been implemented inside Espresso itself. My example is more like a hack.

Comment: 1. https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource#create-own

2. Yes, you are correct, I got an error in my code and got confused.

Thnaks.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov 1) Thanks for the link. Google's suggesting not to do so to avoid an unnecessary second check inside the Espresso. In my opinion, it's not so critical for a TEST if there's an additional check , but feel to provide an example where it matters. 2) I'm glad that it helped!

Comment: I'm trying same  with Wear-OS,Sometimes test will pass or fail,Any suggestion here?

Comment: @Anatolii After more than 3 years, I was wondering if maybe this is still the best way to wait a view? I just tried your code(Used Dmytro Karataiev's kotlin version), it works well. Just curious if Google provide better solutions(I did tried to Google for it:p )

Comment: @hellotli I haven't used Google Espresso for a while, but it looks like it's still the way to go :)

Answer (score 20):

Atte Backenhof's solution has a small bug (or maybe I don't fully understand the logic).

**getView** should return a null instead of throwing an exception to make IdlingResources work.

Here's a Kotlin solution with the fix:

```
/**
 * @param viewMatcher The matcher to find the view.
 * @param idleMatcher The matcher condition to be fulfilled to be considered idle.
 */
class ViewIdlingResource(
    private val viewMatcher: Matcher<View?>?,
    private val idleMatcher: Matcher<View?>?
) : IdlingResource {

    private var resourceCallback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback? = null

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    override fun isIdleNow(): Boolean {
        val view: View? = getView(viewMatcher)
        val isIdle: Boolean = idleMatcher?.matches(view) ?: false
        if (isIdle) {
            resourceCallback?.onTransitionToIdle()
        }
        return isIdle
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    override fun registerIdleTransitionCallback(resourceCallback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback?) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    override fun getName(): String? {
        return "$this ${viewMatcher.toString()}"
    }

    /**
     * Tries to find the view associated with the given [<].
     */
    private fun getView(viewMatcher: Matcher<View?>?): View? {
        return try {
            val viewInteraction = onView(viewMatcher)
            val finderField: Field? = viewInteraction.javaClass.getDeclaredField("viewFinder")
            finderField?.isAccessible = true
            val finder = finderField?.get(viewInteraction) as ViewFinder
            finder.view
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Waits for a matching View or throws an error if it's taking too long.
 */
fun waitUntilViewIsDisplayed(matcher: Matcher<View?>) {
    val idlingResource: IdlingResource = ViewIdlingResource(matcher, isDisplayed())
    try {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(idlingResource)
        // First call to onView is to trigger the idler.
        onView(withId(0)).check(doesNotExist())
    } finally {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(idlingResource)
    }
}
```

Usage in your UI tests:

```
    @Test
    fun testUiNavigation() {
        ...
        some initial logic, navigates to a new view
        ...
        waitUntilViewIsDisplayed(withId(R.id.view_to_wait_for))
        ...
        logic on the view that we waited for
        ...
    }
```

**Important update:** default timeout for the IdlingResources is 30 seconds, they don't wait forever. To increase a timeout you need to call it in @Before method for example:
`IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`

Comment: I am using your code for recyclerview which is being populated on response of an API call. But getting idlingrespurcetimoutexception - to become idle timed out. Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: Check this repo I just created for you, read the code: https://github.com/dmytroKarataiev/RecyclerView-IdlingResource-LongApiDataDelay

Comment: Create a new SO question if you can't figure it out and let me know

Comment: Oh and by the way, you don't want to use real API to test your app. You need to mock out the API.

Comment: Dmytro I am using real APIs. Does your github repo works in that case ? My API usually takes 30 to 90 secs. And I dont want to wait for fixed time.

Comment: It does work with everything, you need to increase a timeout deadline for the idling resources. The default is 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check and will star your repo.

Comment: you should add this in ur answer

IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        ActivityScenario.launch((LandingPageActivity::class.java))

Comment: Dmytro Now I am getting this error - Looped for 30 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed DYNAMIC_TASKS_HAVE_IDLED

Comment: You'll have to share your repo with the code so I can take a look. Hard to say what's going on.

Comment: While the other answer crashed my app on fragment navigation, this one didn't!

Comment: Sometimes, withId(0) matches multiple views, I suggest using -543210 or similar, since generated ids are always positive

Answer (score 5):

I took inspiration from Anatolii, but instead of using methods from the View.class I still only use ViewMatchers.

```
/**
 * {@link IdlingResource} that idles until a {@link View} condition is fulfilled.
 */
public class ViewIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    private final Matcher<View>    viewMatcher;
    private final Matcher<View>    idleMatcher;
    private       ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param viewMatcher The matcher to find the view.
     * @param idlerMatcher The matcher condition to be fulfilled to be considered idle.
     */
    public ViewIdlingResource(final Matcher<View> viewMatcher, Matcher<View> idlerMatcher) {
        this.viewMatcher = viewMatcher;
        this.idleMatcher = idlerMatcher;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        View view = getView(viewMatcher);
        boolean isIdle = idleMatcher.matches(view);

        if (isIdle && resourceCallback != null) {
            resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
        }

        return isIdle;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this + viewMatcher.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Tries to find the view associated with the given {@link Matcher<View>}.
     */
    private static View getView(Matcher<View> viewMatcher) {
        try {
            ViewInteraction viewInteraction = onView(viewMatcher);
            Field finderField = viewInteraction.getClass().getDeclaredField("viewFinder");
            finderField.setAccessible(true);
            ViewFinder finder = (ViewFinder) finderField.get(viewInteraction);
            return finder.getView();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And how to use the idler in your test case, I pass the ViewMatchers.isDisplayed() to be my expected condition in the idler.

```
private void waitUntilViewIsDisplayed(Matcher<View> matcher) {
        IdlingResource idlingResource = new ViewIdlingResource(matcher, isDisplayed());
        try {
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(idlingResource);
            // First call to onView is to trigger the idler.
            onView(withId(0)).check(doesNotExist());
        } finally {
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(idlingResource);
        }
    }
```

With this you can pass any Matcher.class to the ViewIdlingResource constructor to be the required condition for the view found by the viewMatcher parameter.

Answer (score -2):

To wait for a view display and can do action on it. You can use this method:

```
    private const val sleepTime = 1000L
    private const val maximumWaitedTime = 10000L // maximum waited time in milliseconds to wait a view visible

    fun waitViewVisible(viewInteraction: ViewInteraction?, block: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
        waitAssertView(viewInteraction, ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()), block)
    }

    fun waitViewGone(viewInteraction: ViewInteraction?, block: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
        waitAssertView(viewInteraction, ViewAssertions.matches(not(isDisplayed())), block)
    }

    fun waitAssertView(viewInteraction: ViewInteraction?, assertion: ViewAssertion?, block: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
            if (viewInteraction == null || assertion == null) throw NullPointerException()
            val startedTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
            var elapsedTime: Long = 0
            var isVisible = false
            do {
                isVisible = runCatching {
                    viewInteraction.check(assertion)
                }.isSuccess
                if (isVisible) break
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime)
                elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startedTime
            } while (elapsedTime <= maximumWaitedTime)
            if (!isVisible) throw TimeoutException("Waited time exceed the maximum waited time")

            block?.invoke()
        }
```